# Omniture Site Catalyst count getting changed frequently

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am consuming the site catalyst data for different report suites for one of our application. But what i have found is the metrics data is getting changed in Omniture side (though we are downloading data 1 day prior) on refreshing the Page or verifying the data 1 hour later.

for Ex- If we are looking for (Page views, Visits, Daily UV) count for Oct 13 then the count is showing different different values after 1 hour for Oct 13.

Can anybody please suggest what may be the reason for the data get refreshed. As we are storing the data in our end in database it's creating serious issue with data mismatch for various dates.

Waiting for the quick suggestion.
Thanks

Comment: Unless you are using the real-time data API (if that's available now), one hour may not be enough time to wait for the full processing to be completed. If you wait 2 or 3 hours, does it still change within the next hour?

Comment: you should actually wait more than 2-3h for some of those metrics. a visit won't be fully processed until the actual visit is over. It is possible for a visitor to go to your site and be active on your site for hours, days, forever. Also, when you are looking at stuff like Daily UV on that day.. well the day isn't even over yet, so of course it will show more data as the day progresses.  Also, let's not even get into time zones vs. processing. Long story short, if you want "finalized" data snapshots, it's best to look historically, at least a full day or two.